# the meaning of 4-wise hash function

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random, hash-function

If someone says: 4-wise independent sign (hash) functions $s_1,s_2, s_3 : [d] → \{+1, −1\}$, then what does it means? I cannot use k-wise Independence variables
(the definition 1 http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/topics-S13/lec5.pdf) to understand the above 4-wise independent sign (hash) functions, can someone help me, thanks.